# Why does this Java code using multiple constructors run in VS code but won't compile with javac?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, constructor, javac

I've been experimenting with using multiple constructors in Java.  Below is my code:

```java
public class MultipleConstructors {
    int x = 20;
    int y = 50;
    String color = "Green";
    String color2 = "Yellow";

    public MultipleConstructors() {

    }

    public MultipleConstructors(int numb, int numb2, String colOne, String colTwo) {
        x = numb;
        y = numb2;
        color = colOne;
        color2 = colTwo;
    }

    public MultipleConstructors(int numb3, int numb4, String colThree, String colFour) {
        x = numb3;
        y = numb4; 
        color = colThree;
        color2 = colFour;
    }

    public MultipleConstructors(int numb5, int numb6, String colFive, String colSix) {
        x = numb5;
        y = numb6; 
        color = colFive;
        color2 = colSix;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MultipleConstructors myObjOne = new MultipleConstructors(100, 200, "Pink", "Blue");
        MultipleConstructors myObjTwo = new MultipleConstructors(300, 500, "Burgandy", "Silver");
        MultipleConstructors myObjThree = new MultipleConstructors(800, 1000, "Black", "White");
        MultipleConstructors myObjFour = new MultipleConstructors();

        System.out.println(myObjOne.x + myObjOne.y + " " + myObjOne.color + " " + myObjTwo.color2 + " " + " : SUCCESS");

        System.out.println(myObjTwo.x + myObjTwo.y + " " + myObjTwo.color + " " + myObjTwo.color2 + " " + " : VICTORY");

        System.out.println(myObjThree.x + myObjThree.y + " " + myObjThree.color + " " + myObjThree.color2 + " " + " : YES");

        System.out.println(myObjFour.x + myObjFour.y + " " + myObjFour.color + " " + myObjFour.color2 + " " + " : YES");
    }
}
```

It runs in VS Code but will not compile using `javac` command. I think it might be the undefined constructor `public MultipleConstructors() {}` after the parent attribute declarations.

Comment: Run the following command in your terminal(```javac --version```) and if you do not get a version number output probably javac path variable is not set in your machine

Comment: Entered javac --version: 
javac 15.0.1

Comment: Okay so when you try run code in VSCode it works and in terminal does not work nor throw an error?

Comment: Correct, runs in VSCode but won't compile in order to run in terminal. It throws the error "could not find or load main class " caused by "ClassNotFoundException"

Comment: I doubt this compiles in VSCode or otherwise. You have several constructors with the exact same argument types so the compiler can't figure out which one you mean when you call them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get something like the following error message:

```
MultipleConstructors.java:11: error: constructor MultipleConstructors(int,int,java.lang.String,java.lang.String) is already defined in class MultipleConstructors
```

Then you should use this answer.  If you are having a ClassNotFoundException, you should see Ntshembo Hlongwane's answer.

Your issue here is that you have multiple of the same constructor.  I think what you are going for is constructor overloading, which means you can have multiple constructors with different headers, but three of your constructors have the same header.  See my comments inline with your constructors below:

```java
public MultipleConstructors() {
    // header has no parameters
    // fine, leaves values alone
}

public MultipleConstructors(int numb, int numb2, String colOne, String colTwo) {
    // header has parameters int, int String String
    //fine, offers you the opportunity to change those values

    x = numb;
    y = numb2;
    color = colOne;
    color2 = colTwo;
}

public MultipleConstructors(int numb3, int numb4, String colThree, String colFour) {
    // header has parameters int, int, String, String
    // Wait, that's the same as the one above!

    x = numb3;
    y = numb4; 
    color = colThree;
    color2 = colFour;
}

public MultipleConstructors(int numb5, int numb6, String colFive, String colSix) {
    // header has parameters int, int, String, String
    // Wait, that's also the same as the one above!

    x = numb5;
    y = numb6; 
    color = colFive;
    color2 = colSix;
}
```

When you instantiate this object, and you give it two ints and a string, which constructor do you expect to be called?  This is a logic error, not a syntax error or a compiler error, because your code is ambiguous.  Hope this helps, and good luck in your learning journey. :)

Comment: Sorry can I ask how does wrong way of overloading constructors/methods have to do with this exception which was given i.e ```"could not find or load main class " caused by "ClassNotFoundException" ```

Comment: That information was posted after I wrote this answer.  If you want to fix that error, you would use your answer.  That said, once you fix the ClassNotFoundException, you will quickly run into a compile-time error on the constructors.  I would guess OP needs both of our answers.  +1 on yours.

Comment: The exception/error that would be thrown due to wrong approach in constructor/method overloading would be: ```Stack.java:14: error: constructor Stack(int) is already defined in class Stack``` for example

Comment: Alright, thank you, I will incorporate that into my answer.

Comment: It compiled after I changed the data types as Charlie Armstrong suggested.

Comment: @archetypePhaseV Glad to hear that you've got it working :)

Comment: @Charlie Armstrong Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Based on the exception found when running code**

```
Correct, runs in VSCode but won't compile in order to run in terminal. It throws the error "could not find or load main class " caused by "ClassNotFoundException"
```

**This is caused by:**

- Lets say you name your file `Test.java`
- Then in your code you write the class as `MyTest`
- When you try run code `java Test` you get the following error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class Test
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Test
```

- And this is because Java now created a `MyTest.class` that you have to run instead